# "Unknown column in 'field list'", but column does exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, innodb

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transactions`;
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `purchase_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `transactions` (`purchase_date`) VALUES (NULL)
```

I've isolated my problem in this code. When I run it, I get the error:

> [ERROR in query 3] Unknown column 'purchase_date' in 'field list'

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is an unprintable character 30 (RecordSeparator) inserted between `purchase_date` and the `'` in the `INSERT` statement. Just remove the text `('purchase_date')` and rewrite it by hand it should be fine.

Comment: how did you got that there is an unprintable character ??

Comment: Just dumb luck. Click edit, copy the SQL and paste it into an editor that shows unprintables.

Comment: It's usually a trailing space

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. MySQL workbench doesn't show \t tabs. Remove all the whitespace as possible and it will work.

Comment: Use the following command to remove control characters from a file:

`tr -dc '\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376' < file > newfile`

Answer (score 13):

Nery niche solution when I got this error.

I had a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on my table that did something with 
`` NEW.`field_mysql_doesnt_think_exists` ``
 and if I didn't pass that field to an insert statement then I would get

`[ERROR in query 3] Unknown column 'field_mysql_doesnt_think_exists' in 'field list'`

Comment: This answer led me to the problem I was having.

Comment: Thank you! I was mystified about what was happening here.  For others to check for triggers on a table you can use show triggers like 'table_name'.

Comment: Can somebody expand on this answer? I have this same problem but I don't understand the solution.

Answer (score 7):

I just spent the better part of a day figuring this out. My problem was the same: invisible characters kiboshing the query and returning the "unknown column" error.

I solved it by wading back into Windows and removing the garbage using NotePad++.

How did the garbage get in there in the first place? I think it was because I made the mistake of copying some long complex queries into LibreOffice Writer (my functional specs document) instead of just bookmarking them in phpMyAdmin or saving them in a text editor. Pasting them from LibreOffice into the query window is where (I think) the garbage originated.

Once there, it persisted like Malaria. I couldn't even get rid of it by hand-retyping the whole query -- I had to put it into NotePad++ (Encoding menu) and show ANSI and the UTF8 combos and then remove the garbage by hand.

Once that was done, the query worked.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you paste a column name when building the table structure. Same error - but the unprintable/invisible characters are in the table structure, not the query.

Answer (score 1):

This might not help anyone else, but adding this "just in case" it helps someone.

I receive large datasets as Excel CSV files and use a (WIL) script to convert the .csv file into an importable .sql file.

I had an error in my conversion script whereby these two lines did not reference the same table name (I had hard-coded the first location and forgot to update it):

```
* "INSERT INTO `old_table_name` (`cid`, `date`, etc etc"
* "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `":_dbName:"` (etc etc "
```

I just changed the first line to also get the table name from the variable, and voila!

```
* "INSERT INTO `":_dbName:"` (`cid`, `date`, etc etc"
```

So check those two lines in your import SQL file.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue this morning and I didn't find my answer.
But I found my problem when I changed the single quotes around my query to double quotes. Something so small and an oversight can cause a real headache.

Unknown column x in "field list" - Code below wrapped in single quotes - Non working.

```
    $likepost='INSERT INTO reaction(reaction_num,userreaction_id,timereacted,
    streamitem_id,comment_posted_on) 
    VALUES ($reaction,$target,NOW(),$streamid,$comment_id)';
```

Code below wrapped in double quotes. working

```
    $likepost="INSERT INTO reaction(reaction_num,userreaction_id,timereacted,
    streamitem_id,comment_posted_on) 
    VALUES ($reaction,$target,NOW(),$streamid,$comment_id)";
```

Comment: You da man!!! I doubt I would have guessed this for days so thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help. You wouldn't think it would make a difference would you, but it's the smallest mistakes we make that bring the biggest problems, so if I make a mistake and find someone else has, I'm always happy to help, as everyone would with me if I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is caused by an unprintable character in a column name I used a query like this to find which column was bad.  I regularly import csv data using a python script in Linux.  The csv was created from converting a windows xl spreadsheet.  There was something at the very beginning of the file, preprocessing it with dos2unix appears to have removed whatever was there.

```
mysql> select id from yourtablename;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(COLUMN_NAME USING ASCII) as name
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
    +----------------------------------+
    | name                             |
    +----------------------------------+
    | ?id                              |
    | first                            |
    | last                             |
    | name                             |
    | costcenter                       |
    +----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error in a different scenario:

This also happens when you miss @ symbol for a variable.

```
SET @myVar1=1;  SELECT @myVar1;  -- GOOD, correctly prints:  1
SET @myVar1=1;  SELECT  myVar1;  -- BAD, prints:  Unknown column 'myVar1' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to work with mysql using a function like this:

```
function insert($table, $info_array){
    // implode keys as columns by [`,`] glue string
    $columns = implode("`,`", array_keys($info_array));

    // implode values as sql ready values by [','] glue string
    $values = implode("','", array_values($info_array));

    // make query(careful about [`] for columns name and ['] for values)
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`".$columns."`) VALUES ('".$values."');";
    return $sql;
}
```

you should be careful about **[ ` ] for table columns names** and **[ ' ] or [ " ] for values**.
for example, I used above function this way:

```
try{
        $db_insert_sample_user = $connection->query(insert(TABLE_PREFIX."users", [
            "username" => "my_name_2",
            "password" => md5("how457fty")
        ]));
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($db_insert_sample_user);
        echo '</pre>';
    }catch (PDOException $exc){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($exc);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

the query string is this:

```
INSERT INTO php_pdo_users (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('my_name_2','ee04708d313adf4ff8ba321acf3eb568');
```

and the result was like : (for two users)
[PHPMyAdmin Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ibN.png)

if you want functions based on prepared statements, test this : (**placeholders, params and values, don't need [ ' ] or [ " ] at all!!!**)

```
function insert_prepared(PDO $connection, $table, $info_array){
    // columns
    $columns = implode("`,`", array_keys($info_array));

    // placeholders
    $place_holders = [];
    for ( $i = 0; count(array_keys($info_array)) > $i; $i++){
        $place_holders[] = '?';
    }

    // convert placeholders to query string
    $place_holders_str = implode(",", $place_holders);
    $prepared_stmt = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`".$columns."`) VALUES (".$place_holders_str.");";

    // prepare statement
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($prepared_stmt);

    // values
    $values = array_values($info_array);

    // bind all params to values
    for($i = 0; count($values) > $i; $i++){
        $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $values[$i]);
    }

    // execute and return results
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

after code execution this way :

```
try {
        $db_insert_sample_user = insert_prepared(
            $connection,
            TABLE_PREFIX . "users",
            [
                "username" => "my_name_4",
                "password" => md5( "HelloDolly#__3" )
            ]
        );
    } catch ( PDOException $exc ) {
        echo "Failed : " . $exc->getMessage();
    }
```

results is :
[Results with `insert_prepared` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmH0W.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was using a mysql procedure and in the procedure parameter I used `phone`  with an extra space instead of `phone` with no extra space, due to this when ever I called the function. It just throw error no such column as `phone` . Until I miraculously spotted it and corrected it using phpMyAdmin, Error went off.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same PYMYSQL error in my Python program when I found this answer.

I probably violated a Pandas rule when I created a new dataframe ...

**This created same the error above: A phantom column**

```
inddata = dat[['ind_id','iso3c','date','data']]
dat.to_sql(name='inddata', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=200)
```

**This fixed the error:**

```
dat2 = dat[['ind_id','iso3c','date','data']]
inddata = dat2.copy()
dat.to_sql(name='inddata', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=200)
```

Answer (score -3):

Look at the name of the table you are handling

Comment: Hey Muxavisse, Your answer doesn't really explain a lot. Your answer is at best a comment.