# MySQL Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'field' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I keep getting

> Error Code: 1054
>   Unknown column 'originalFieldName' in 'field list'

when trying to insert a new record to a table. This still happens even when I am not inserting any value to this problematic column 'originalFieldName'. Renaming the field and ensuring I don't have unprintable characters like suggested in solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989529/unknown-column-in-field-list-but-column-does-exist) does not help either.

I have since reduced my query to 
`INSERT INTO incoming(receiptDate)
VALUES(NOW());`
and deleted some fields to remain with below table:
[table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AygoW.jpg)
but this error 1054 keeps popping up

Comment: Not making scene , maybe you still have he previous error in the console.

Comment: Check the triggers that you have.

Comment: @Mjh thanks. I have deleted triggers associated with that table and insert query now works

Answer (score 4):

The error was caused by a trigger which was doing a comparison on 'originalFieldName'. I had forgotten to specify it as `new.originalFieldName` to refer to the newly inserted value in that field and thus MySQL reported it as unknown column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mysql ? If you are using mysql then there could be a difference in back tick ( `someValue ` ) . Keep considering this point and see if it helps . If you are using other DB then please let me know . It seems some invisible characters has been introduced there . May be you have copied it from somewhere . Please let me know DB details and paste full code.

Comment: Why it has been down voted ? Do you know what does it means ?

Comment: Probably because this shouldn't be an answer but a comment. If anything, I don't think your answer has anything to do with OP's problem. (I'm not the one who downvoted though)

Comment: Backticks have nothing to do with this issue. Try to replicate and see for yourself. I didn't downvote, but you did provide a wrong answer.

Comment: sometimes if we copy code from somewhere then we get some other character at place of quote or back tick . I used the word COULD not MUST.

Comment: There is a difference between  (“`”) and ("`")

Comment: I did not have much reputation to comment there , so i have thought to give an answer so that he will get a way which may be true ..

Comment: @ManishSoni someone (not me) probably downvoted you because you were not keen in reading the question. One, I don't have backticks in the insert query I provided. Two, my question starts with "MySQL Error..." so there was no reason to ask if I am using mysql