# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'adjusted_amount' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

***I have tried lot's of times and debugged but till now i can't find out where is the problem? Any kinds of help appreciated.***

**Error:**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 662: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'adjusted_amount' in 'field list' (SQL:
>   update `tbl_bill_collection` set `dueamount` = 0, `adjusted_amount` =
>   100, `adjusted_by` = 5302, `adjusted_date` = 2016-12-20 21:19:31 where
>   `billno` = 7777)

**In My Controller Code:**

> ```
>         DB::table( 'bill_collection' )
>         ->where( 'billno', 555 )
>         ->update([
>             'dueamount'     => $request->input( 'dueamount' ),
>             'adjusted_amount' => $request->input( 'adjustment' ),
>             'adjusted_by'   => Auth::User()->id,
>             'adjusted_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
>         ]);
> ```

**My database table column images given below:**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking at the correct **database**?

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely invisible characters being the problem, like here: ["Unknown column in 'field list'", but column does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989529/unknown-column-in-field-list-but-column-does-exist)

Re-type the query by hand and see if that helps.

Comment: Re-typed the query by hand but still same problem.