# Why am I getting Unknown column '' in 'field list' (sequelize)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working with node, express and sequelize (I'm pretty new with all these three) and I'm getting `"Unknown column 'productTeam' in 'field list'"` in what I think is the simplest possible scenario:

In my backend code, I have the following:

```js
    const repos = await ScasRepo.findAll(
        {
            where: {"productId": productId}
        }
    )
```

I can see that the generated query is as follows:

```
Executing (default):
SELECT `id`, `productTeam`, `productId`
FROM `ScasRepos` AS `ScasRepo`
WHERE `ScasRepo`.`productId` = '10519';
```

And this is what my table looks like:

```
mysql> describe ScasRepos;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| productId      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| productTeam    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see, the `productTeam` field is defined in the table, so why am I getting an error message saying `"Unknown column 'productTeam' in 'field list'"`?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Note that the generated query is filtering for `productId  = '10519'`, while the productId should be an integer, not a string. I doubt this causes the error you are getting though.

Comment: @Vvdl thanks for the heads up. As you expected, fixing that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Might be a long shot, but can it be possible the top answer to this very old question is your issue as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989529/unknown-column-in-field-list-but-column-does-exist

Comment: maybe the productTeam in the database is saved with a space in the end, like 'productTeam '?

Comment: @rszf thanks for the input but I just ran this query `select * from ScasRepos where productTeam='X';` directly in MySQL and it worked, so I guess the name is written properly.

Comment: and if you execute the generated query directly? does it also fail?